# Prevent spaces in textbox being enterd

Tags: vba, spaces

Got a textbox in VBA and dont want the usser to be able to type spaces in it can i prevent the usser from doing this with programing?

Comment: vba for which product?  Excel?  Access?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the keypress/[change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211341%28office.11%29.aspx) event, check for " " then set to string.empty.

Alternativly use string.replace(" ", string.empty) after the data has been entered

Comment: I thought about ussing the string replace but this alows the user to still type ussing spaces in the textbox with VBA fishing these out when writing the string?

Comment: That would be one way to do it... regardless, handling the event should be the 'when' part, 'how' is up to you :)

Comment: "string.empty" is a .NET field.  User would need to put _""_ or declare an _EMPTY_STRING_ constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
' Disable Space in TextBox
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 32 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=447978

From google :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://forum.vb-paradise.de/allgemeines/tipps-tricks-und-tutorials/allgemein/3426-nur-zahlen-in-einer-textbox-erlauben/) will help you:

You can allow/disallow specific buttons in the KeyPress-Event

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case asc("0") To asc("9"), 8, 32, asc(",")
      'allow signs
    Case Else
       KeyAscii = 0 'forbid everything else
  End Select
End Sub
```

NOTE: This example allows only numbers to be entered. You need to adapt it for your case.

Here is another page with nearly the same example but in english: [LINK](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_allow_letters_numbers.html)

Comment: I like this example but could you break it down for me please

Comment: I think the example is very easy to understand. Another hint i can give you is the ascii code for a space is 32.

Comment: ah okay it looks simple dont get me wrong, Im self taught in vba (not pro) ill be able to work from here